# Copying Files from one directory to another with Threads

Tags: java, apache-commons, java-threads, fileutils

I'm trying to copy files from one directory to another.

But as I have to copy them at the same time, I've though that could be nice to use Threads so my software do not get freeze while copying.

The problem is that Threads should be closed (manually), and I don't know which is the callback where I can subscribe to know when the copying process ends.

To acomplish the copying task I'm using Java library `apache.commons.io.FileUtils` using mainly the function `copyFileToDirectory`

And my code looks like:

```
//Thread to copy files from one place to another
    public void CopyFileFromTo(String file, String fromDirectoryName, String destinationDirectoryName) throws IOException
    {
        //TODO: Establish when the thread has ended, no callbacks for CopyFileToDirectory? :(
        //Copy from file to directory
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {                   
            Path src = Paths.get(fromDirectoryName+"\\"+file);
            Path dest = Paths.get(destinationDirectoryName);
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(src.toFile(),dest.toFile());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: *The problem is that Threads should be closed (manually)*: where did you read that? They shouldn't. There isn't any close() method in Thread, BTW.

Comment: This looks ok. The thread will end when the run() method ends. But I don't think you will get any benefit copying multiple files in parallel(it will probably even have adverse effect).

Comment: Also your approach here is incorrect. First of all you're not using threads but a single thread for each file to be copied. This is not very good performance wise as you'll be spawning a new thread for every call to this method. Also, by using a runnable there is no way for you to know whether the copying action has succeeded or failed. I suggest you use the Callable/Future combination along with a pooled executor service.

Comment: If you want your code to work on all platforms, use `Paths.get(fromDirectoryName, file)` instead of hard coding `"\\"`.  Also, you don’t need Apache Commons for this;  just use `Files.copy(src, dest.resolve(file));`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. So I missunderstood how Threads work JB Nizet, I was especting that Threads were an infinite loop that SHOULD close (with conditionals or just return). But still having questions: NeplatnyUdaj why parallel tasks will have adverse effect? @Aris_Kortex if I use one thread for every call, it's not using Threads? why? I will also try Callable/Future combinations, I like the approach (what about CompletableFuture?). VGR Thanks, you're right.